# Downloading satellite imagery from German cities (zoomlevel > 13)

Tags: satellite

I am looking for a way to download satellite imagery for later use with ml similar to this:

[image]

I have to download quite a number of these images so downloading directly from Google Maps isn't really an option.

Service may be free or paid if its not too costly

Comment: To Down-voter, please add comment(s) why (any reason). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how pur "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. Downloading from Google Maps would violate their TOS, so that never was an option. What is missing from this question is an indication of research on how to obtain imagery. Also, "ml" is unclear.

Comment: @Kazuhito It would be more useful to suggest improvements than to attempt communication with those who have already left the posting behind.

Comment: Aah, yes. I now understand the reason from your comment. Thanks @Vince. Piracy is not allowed whatever in its style!

Comment: I doubt that is satellite imagery in your image. Actually, I am almost certain it is not.

Comment: are you searching for free services only or also for paid ones?

Comment: free or paid if its not to costly

Answer (score 0):

You state that the service can be paid so you can pay for that exact imagery via the Google Imagery Sales program at
https://support.google.com/mapsdata/answer/6250079?hl=en

Comment: can you provide me with an actual link to the product? I have trouble finding it.